# javascript dynamically add values to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to loop over the checkboxes in a form and add their values to a multidimensional javascript object. The '`attrib`' data attribute will be the key. Possible key values are '`category`', '`product_group`' and '`language`' but I'd rather add them dynamically in case any more get added in the future.

I want to end up with an object like this, which I can easily send as a json_encode 'd single value to the server.

```
values = {
    'category' : {1,2,3},
    'product_group' : {4,5,6},
    'language': {'en','fr','de'}
};
```

Code below. Here obviously each iteration overwrites existing values instead of adding to it. I'm unsure where I can create values[key] as an object ... ?

```
$('.filter input, .multiselect-container input').change(function() {
    var values = {}
    $('.filter input:checked').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var key = $(this).data('attrib')
            var value = $(this).val()
            values[key] = value
            // values[key].push(value) = calling method push of undefined ...
        }
        else {
            // Remove value
        }       
    })
    console.log(values) 
})
```

Comment: Of course for a new `values[key]`, that hasn’t been accessed so far, trying to call `.push` will fail, because there is no array to call that method on yet. So check first, if that element is an array already – if not, initialize it as a new array first, and then push the next value to it afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is due to the fact that `values[key]` is `undefined`, therefore does not have a `push` method.

Try this code:

```
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var key = $(this).data('attrib')
            var value = $(this).val()
            values[key] = values[key] || [] // initialize with empty array
            values[key].push(value)
        }
```

Comment: Works! The double pipes line basically means, create a new array if it doesn't exist yet, and avoids having to use an if() statement? Never seen that before, thanks.

Comment: Double pipes line is the logical OR operator [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FLogical_Operators]. This usage is a common way to provide defaults. Use with care though, because any falsy value will be overwritten with the default, not just `undefined` or `null`. In this case you have no worries, because arrays are always truthy.

Comment: I knew double pipes = OR, just wondering what it meant in this context. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's what you are looking for:

```
if(!values[key])
   values[key]=new Array();

values[key].push(value);
```

But this way you can add an array of value to every key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var key = $(this).data('attrib')
            var value = $(this).val()
            if(typeof values[key]  == "undefined")
            values[key] = [];
            values[key].push(value);

        }
        else {
            // Remove value
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your data representation is not correct. The object attributes should be arrays like this:

```
values = {
    'category' : [1,2,3],
    'product_group' : [4,5,6],
    'language': ['en','fr','de']
};
```

With that data representation, this piece of code will do what you want:

```
$('.filter input, .multiselect-container input').change(function() {
var values = {}
$('.filter input:checked').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var key = $(this).data('attrib')
        var value = $(this).val()
        values[key] = value
        if (values.key == undefined){
            //Check if key exists. If not, create it as an array
            values[key] = Array()
            values[key].push(value)
        }
        else{
            values[key].push(value)
        }
    }
    else {
        // Remove value
    }       
})
console.log(values)
```

})